# как распарсить xml в рнр?

Tags: xml, simplexml

Есть xml примерно такого вида:

```
$xml1 = "<?xml version='1.0'?>
<workers>
    <fg>
        <worker name='Коля' age='25' salary='1000'>Номер 1</worker>
        <worker name='Вася' age='26' salary='2000'>Номер 2</worker>
        <worker name='Петя' age='27' salary='3000'>Номер 3</worker>
    </fg>
</workers>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml1);

foreach ($xml as $worker) {
    echo $xml->worker['name']; 
    echo $xml->worker['age']; 
    echo $xml->worker['salary']; 
    echo $xml->worker; 
}
```

такой вариант не работает.

Answer (score 0):

- Обращаться к дочерним элементам можно через `->`
- `worker` - это массив. Если распечатать, то можно увидеть

  ```
  SimpleXMLElement Object
  (
      [fg] => SimpleXMLElement Object
          (
              [worker] => Array
                  (
                      [0] => Номер 1
                      [1] => Номер 2
                      [2] => Номер 3
                  )        
          )    
  )
  ```

Соответственно, зная это, применяем:

```
$xmlString = "<?xml version='1.0'?>
<workers>
    <fg>
        <worker name='Коля' age='25' salary='1000'>Номер 1</worker>
        <worker name='Вася' age='26' salary='2000'>Номер 2</worker>
        <worker name='Петя' age='27' salary='3000'>Номер 3</worker>
    </fg>
</workers>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
// добираемся с помощью '->' до 'worker' и т.к. это массив - перебираем его
foreach ($xml->fg->worker as $worker) {
    echo 'number: ' . ((string)$worker) .'. name: ' . $worker['name'] . 
    ', age: ' . $worker['age'] . ', salary: ' . $worker['salary'] . '<br/>';         
}
```

Comment: Но там еще есть " Номер 1", " Номер 2", " Номер 3"

Comment: @Виталий ну добавьте еще `$worker` → `echo 'number: ' . $worker .'. name: ' . $worker['name'] . ', age: ' . $worker['age'] . ', salary: ' . $worker['salary'] . '<br/>';`

Comment: спасибо!!! теперь понятно как.